# Logo on the center with time

Tags: javascript, web, graphical-logo

How can I make the website logo in the center pages for 10 seconds?

I tried:

```
var ddsitelogo={
    setting: {orientation:4, visibleduration:30, fadeduration:[1000, 500]}, //orientation=1|2|3|4, duration=millisec or 0, fadedurations=millisecs
    offsets: {x:10, y:10},//offset of logo relative to window corner
    logoHTML: '<img src="logo_center.PNG" style="width:80px; height:40px; border:0" /></a>', //HTML for logo, which is auto wrapped in DIV w/ ID="mysitelogo"
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume how to know how to access the json you provided.

```
/* put code here to SHOW the logo */
window.setTimeout(function() {
    /* code to HIDE the logo */
}, 10000);
```

Last param is milli seconds when to call the function.

If you are using jQuery, you can hide the image with `$(yourLogoSelector).hide();`.

You should put the above codeblock when the dom is ready, with jQuery, it's

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* dom is ready */
});
```

To center the image, you can apply styles to the container, see http://api.jquery.com/css/